Terraform resource group name for the creation of alerts for azure front door
Implementing an alert through terraform for the azure frontdoor status.
having an example for the virtual machines
  name                = "resource_health_alert"
  description         = "Resource Health Alerts"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  scopes              = [var.scope]
  criteria {
    resource_id    = var.resource_id
    category       = "ResourceHealth"
    resource_type  = "microsoft.compute/Virtual machines" 
    resource_group = ""
    resource_health {
         current = ["Degraded","Unavailable","Unknown"]
         previous = ["Available"]
         reason = ["PlatformInitiated","UserInitiated","Unknown"]
    }
  }
  action {
    action_group_id = var.action_group_id
  }
  tags = var.tags
}

but looking for the front door proper resource type to trigger an alerts

Hi @Saikumar, do you want to create an alert for the azure front door status suing Terraform. Here is the Front door resource type: "Microsoft.Network/frontDoors"


Creating the alerts for azure front door using terraform

Since the configuration has nothing to match with the required as it requirement relates with Azure frond door but not virtual machines.
As @VenkatV mentioned Need to make some changes respect to resource type and parameters inside resource health as mentioned below to achieve this requirement.
Configuration:
resource "azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert" "res-7" {
  name                = "Frontdoorstatusalert1"
  resource_group_name = "vinay-webapp"
  location            = "Global "
  scopes              = ["/subscriptions/Sub_ID"]
  action {
    action_group_id = "/subscriptions/Sub_ID/resourcegroups/vinay-webapp/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/application insights smart detection"
  }
  criteria {
    category        = "ResourceHealth"
    resource_groups = ["vinay-webapp"]
    resource_ids    = ["/subscriptions/Sub_ID/resourceGroups/vinay-webapp/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/vinayfrontdoor"]
    resource_types  = ["Microsoft.Cdn/profiles"]
    resource_health {
         current = ["Degraded","Unavailable","Available"]
         previous = ["Available"]
         reason = ["PlatformInitiated","UserInitiated","Unknown"]  
    }
  }
}

Deployment:

Refer:
azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
